# Grammar returns either first or everything but first

Tags: bison, yacc

I have these grammars:

```
input : INPUT identifier SEMICOLON { gen(IN, $2, VOID, VOID); }
    ;

identifier : IDENTIFIER identifier_cont   {
                                              installed($1, 2);
                                              $$ = $1;
                                          }
    ;

identifier_cont : /*epsilon*/
    | COMMA IDENTIFIER identifier_cont    {
                                              installed($2, 2);
                                              $$ = $2;
                                          }
    ;
```

There is code generation (`IN x VOID VOID`) that happens with this, but I am having trouble with a list of inputs.

As it is now only the first variable of the input statement:

```
input x, y, x;

// ----

IN x VOID VOID
```

gets generated because of `$$ = $1` on line 5.

Sometimes that needs to be `$$ = $2` so it generates everything but the first variable.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your naming is very confusing.  Your `identifier` rule would be better called `identifier_list` rather than `identifier`, as it matches a comma-separated list of identifiers, rather than a single identifier.

Once you do that, things become clearer.  As `identifier_list` matches a list of idenitifers, it should return a list as `$$` rather than a single identifier.  You can do that by building a list in the action:

```
identifier_list:
        IDENTIFIER { $$ = new_singleton_list($1); }
      | idenitifer_list ',' IDENTIFIER {
            $$ = append_list($1, $3); }
```

So now your top level rule becomes something like:

```
input: INPUT identifer_list ';' {
            for (auto element : $1) {  // iterator over the list
                gen(IN, element, VOID, VOID); } }
```